# Lazy Loading Objects in Map Function in React

Tags: wordpress, reactjs

I am setting up a React/ word press blog.  I am looking to have the posts lazy load when scrolling down the page.

I have a map function in the code below which currently creates a new post object for each post.  My question is when i render my POSTS object and that map function runs ( is it too late to lazy load the individual POST objects?

My goal is to only load/show a handful of posts and load more as the user reaches the end of those posts.

Any help or good plugins you could point me to would be very helpful.

```
Posts = React.createClass({
render(){

var posts = (this.state.posts);

  return (
      <div className="main-feed">
        {posts.map(function(post){
           // create a new Post object ( working ) 
           return <Post post={post} mediaID={post.featured_media} key={post.id} />
         })}
      </div>
  )
 }
})
```

Comment: You want an "infinite scrolling" solution. There are many ways to achieve it, both server and client side. This is too broad to answer on stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes but i think when i render my <Posts /> all of my <Post /> objects render at that time in the map function.  I am not sure if it is possible to implement a lazy load / infinite scroll feature on my Post objects.  Just looking for clarification there